# Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

Got a bit of a problem - my current DNS and apache setup allows my site to be accessed from both http://domain.com/ and http://www.domain.com/. However, the CMS application currently in use requires the URL be http://www.domain.com/, or problems arise.

For the sake of argument, consider modifying the CMS as out of the question. How would I force http://domain.com/ to redirect to http://www.domain.com/ on a DNS/Apache level? I don't have much experience with DNS acrobatics, and .htaccess is pretty multifaceted so it's hard to pin down a proper solution. Therefore, I'm relying on your opinions and expertise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not the answer to your question but if you need a quick solution while you work on this and figure it out, you could always throw in a javascript file at `http://domain.com/` to perform a client redirect.

Comment: Check out [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) - Particularly the section *Canonical Hostnames*

Comment: @MikeChristensen - this'll work for now. Thanks!